# Why is Window 8 printscreen function is slow~ with Remote Desktop to Local 'Paint'

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-paint

I got my new laptop, and its window 8, I often print screen From Remote Desktop and paste the image to my local PAINT so I can save it in my local computer.

When using my old laptop, its always fast and paste within 1 second, but with my new Laptop, its really slow, it takes 30 sec to paste it on the the PAINT.

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you hit print screen you are printing on the remote machine, not your local machine. So, when you paste, you are then copying from the remote clipboard to your local clipboard.

The way around this is to ensure your RDP has lost focus. So, have the RDP visible but select your local machine's task bar so the focus is lost from the RDP. Now, you do print screen on your local machine but since your RDP is still visible, it will of course capture everything.

Why it was faster with your old machine could be many reasons because you also have to options to share folders/clipboards etc so your settings could well have been different.

Comment: is thre any way i can make this work faster by changing any setting in my laptop?  thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to play with the settings in your Local Resources (in your RDP options). Under the Local devices and resources is an option for Clipboard and More (Which allows you to map which may alter speed but not certain).

Comment: @Clo Can you try a print screen and paste into paint without RDP just to rule out RDP as a problem then please?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way out:
Do not maximize the Remote Desktop but expand in such a way that it just covers the local desktop. Now screen captured in Remote Desktop can be quickly pasted into local paint or word. Hope this helps